# Special chars with Jaspersoft iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, special-characters, ireport

I use Jaspersoft iReport v. 3.7.1. I have to display on the report variables returned by two string that represents the a checked and unchecked checkbox, defined as:

```
private final static String unchecked = Character.toString((char)0x2610);
private final static String checked = Character.toString((char)0x2611);
```

Then, I have a `String` like:

```
String toBePrinted = "SEX: "+unchecked+" M\t"+checked+" F";
```

which has to be printed. When I try to print this string, only `"SEX: M  F"` is shown! Probably these codes are not interpreted when the pdf is built.

Any idea?

Comment: I believe this is in relation to the type of PDF font, and encoding.  I tried to deal with this before, but I ended up giving up and using X and _ instead.

Comment: This is nearly always because the font does not contain that character.

Comment: Uuuh! Ok, that's not a great problem, but... very annoying!

Comment: Jasper-Reports have a font-extension jar. Have you tried to use it?

Comment: I've found these two related questions, hope they'll help you: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/522977/pdf-doesnt-display-all-characters   and   http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/529013/unicode-support-and-pdf